# Promise with await returning pending

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read the answers to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). I am still a little confused why this piece of code isn't working correctly.
bool is returning "Promise {pending}", which it should not, since I've put the await keyword there.

db.js:

```
async function validateUser(username, password) {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
  var values = [username, password];

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql,values, function(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (results.length > 0){
        console.log('true');
        resolve("true");
      }
      else{
        console.log('false');
        reject("false");
      }
    }) 
  });
  let bool = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)
  return bool;
}
```

Comment: `bool` is definitely not a promise. However, the `async function` call `validateUser(…)` will return a promise for the boolean to be returned in the future. Instead, you need to put the `await` on the call where you actually want to use the promise result.

Comment: Don't use `throw err` but `reject(err)`! Also, what database library is that? You might not need the `new Promise` wrapper at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions always return a promise. So if you try to log the return value of `validateUser`, it will give you a `Promise`.

Any non-promise value you return from an `async` function is implicitly wrapped in a `Promise`.

You can chain a `.then()` function to the `async` function call to get the resolved value.

```
validateUser(username, password)
  .then(value => console.log(value))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Looking at your code, it seems that you don't need an `async` function at all. You can make `validateUser` a regular function and just return a promise from the `validateUser` function.

```
function validateUser(username, password) {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
  var values = [username, password];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql,values, function(err, results) {
      if (err) reject(err);

      if (results.length > 0) resolve("true");
      else reject("false");
    }) 
  });
}
```

You can also check if the database library you are using provides a `Promise` based API. If it does, you can just use `async-await` syntax instead of using a callback version to query the database and wrapping that in a `Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to `await validateUser(...)`; otherwise you'll get the promise that would eventually resolve.